# Not able to debug phonegap app running on windows 8 mobile

Tags: weinre

I have a phonegap application that has some layout problems. I can run the app in browser for the most part, and this usually get me over the line. But with a new design I need to debug the application layout on windows phone 8.

I'm currently looking at weinre but its not showing anything on the desktop when browsing the local server, I have added the link to my application I have cleaned up everything I can think of. Still blank. Any good tuts around the ones I have read just copy and paste the original docs or are not on my same error.

Answer (score 0):

There's a public weinre server available here:

- https://the-weinre.herokuapp.com/

You may have better luck with that than with your local server.  There's a demo available on that page, give that a try and see if it works on your windows 8 mobile device.